# Ubuntu 14.04 wont boot after entering harddrive encryption password

Tags: boot, grub2, password, encryption

I have installed 14.04 LTS on to my Samsung 850 pro SSD and it was working fine then last time I booted it, it took three attempts to boot. Basically the request for the password appears and I enter it and it says successful. Suddenly some text appears of it setting up and then a black screen and that is it. I have now tried to boot about 12 times now and every time I get to the same point that it accepts my password and then a black screen. I have most of my stuff backed up which is lucky but I don't want to have to reinstall if possible. How can I sort this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Comment: // , Except not really.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the answer. On one attempt Grub loaded and then it worked properly. I have no idea what triggered this and have restarted again and it works. I guess it relates to this:

[How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Basically I think that this is just the generic blank screen that many people have had

Comment: // , Did this solution end up working more consistently? Hast considered filing a bug report?

Comment: No I did not. I know I should have. Can I still do it? It was really weird as it started working and then completely stopped. I have quite a new setup. A gtx 970 and  samsung 850 ssd. I was wondering if these newer components would be the problem? I ended up using ubuntu 15.04 and it sometimes is a problem getting to the unlock LUKS screen. Its the keyboard that just wont work as well when that screen boots up.

Comment: // , I would absolutely file a bug report. Here's why: Not many people use encryption, especially not full disk encryption, and those who do are liable to freak out if things like this happen. Micro$hit has thousands of people to test every edge case with newer hardware. GNU/Linux has not. That's how we pay for the use of the software, by giving back. I have a feeling that this problem is a lot more common than we think, because of how hard it is for someone to admit that they may have their encryption screwed up. Hast a launchpad account? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Done the report. I also found another on the LUKS with 15.04

Comment: // , Wouldst update the question?